# How to Tranpose Array with .EntireRow?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range, transpose

I have following Array which stores values found from a search function.

```
If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Value Not Found"
    Else
    For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
    Array1(i) = FoundCell.Value    'Instead of .Value I can use .Row but .EntireRow doesn't work
    i = i + 1
    Next FoundCell
    j = i - 1
    i = 1
End If
```

I then extract data from the array using transpose which works for '.Value' and '.Row' but I can not extract the whole row from each found value by '.EntireRow'.

```
Range("A1:A" & UBound(Array1) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array1)
```

I tried to change the range in several way's, but nothing seem to fit the .EntireRow criteria.

Update after comment from loannis:

How can I use EntireRow in my array to transpose all the rows to a target location based on the search results stored in FoundCell?

I am using the FindAll search function from cpearson http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx

Comment: This is a typical description of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In addition, your comment on the answer below seems a different question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: In my question I might not have pointed out enough, that I want to transpose all the rows based on the multiple search results stored in Array 1. I will update my question.
As far as I understand I can't do this with the code from sorcery. But maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract an entire row like this however it is a two dimensional array.

```
Sub MethodName()
    Dim Array1
    'Get all the cell values in row A
    Array1 = Cells(1, 1).EntireRow
    Dim i As Integer
    'loop through the array and output the contents to the 2nd row
    For i = 1 To UBound(Array1, 2)
        Cells(2, i).Value = Array1(1, i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using the FindAll function from CPearson
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx
I am not yet sure for how to use this when my array finds multiple search results.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that for the purpose of which I am doing this for, I might as well scrap the array and do it like this:

```
If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Value Not Found"
    Else
    For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
    FoundCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" &   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Next FoundCell

End If
```